# dangerouslysetinnerhtml doesn't embed iframe in react

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I have an text editor to write  the blogs. When i hit submit, data will be saved in the server. But it saves the data in the format of  respective tags. If i write a paragraph then it will be stored in following format in the server.

```
<p>Hi hello world</p>
```

So when I display the content of editor from the server , I use dangerouslysetinnerhtml to convert.

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: b.description }}></div>
```

It converts most of the tags. But now consider that I have this data  stored in the server. Now if i display it, it just displays   instead of embedding the video.How can I achieve this??

Comment: Guess you missed to post the not displayed snippet

Comment: I hope that you know what you doing, you are making your site vulnerable to XSS attack. Please take a time watch this very nice talk. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O91hJJ5KMLs